# R code execution error

Tags: r, import, execution

When I try to import a data set from text file, an error appears:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Joana/Documents/EstatÃƒÂ­stica_R/Densidade PopulaÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂ£o/Density/Dados_Cascavel_quadrantes.csv': No such file or directory
```

This happens with all of the csv/txt files I have. Somebody know what can I do?

My Rstudio version is 0.97.551.

Comment: Can you copy the command that produced this error to the question?

Comment: You're not pointing to the file correctly. `file.choose()` will give you the correct path. I personally don't use spaces or localized characters for file or folder names.

Comment: That's a lot of unusual symbols in the directory names. Have you tried creating a file directly in Documents?

Comment: The problem solved itself, I've know idea how or why. This happened with every files, no matter the directory or the filename.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but it only happened with that one csv. I looked into what was different and found, that the solution was simply special characters in the name of the file. When I removed the "ä" I had in the name, it worked perfectly fine. Might be a bit too late... but to everyone who sees this in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the non-ASCII characters in the file and directory names. Move the CSV to the directory `C:/Users/Joana/Documents/` and rename it to `test.csv`. Then try to open it again: I bet it will work.

I have no idea how to solve that -- it works fine on my Unix system, whereas you are on Windows. See also [this stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934856/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-data-files) question.