# Making non-ASCII data suitable for CRAN

Tags: r, portability, cran

I have some data that contains non-ASCII characters, that I want to include as an `rda` file in an R package.  When I run an `R CMD check` on the package, I get a warning:

```
Warning: found non-ASCII strings
```

which is blocking it being allowed on CRAN.

There's a similar question about [removing non-ASCII characters from data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934856/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-data-files), but I want to keep the non-ASCII characters.

You can grab the CSV data [here](https://github.com/richierocks/learningr/blob/master/inst/extdata/english_monarchs.csv).  I'm reading it into R and resaving as `rda` with this code:

```
english_monarchs <- read.csv(
  wherever_you_downloaded_the_file_to, 
  fileEncoding     = "utf8",
  na.strings       = ""
)
save(english_monarchs, "english_monarchs.csv")
```

It's the `name` column of the dataset that contains non-ascii values.

```
head(levels(english_monarchs$name))
## [1] "Adda"                                "Æðelbehrt"                          
## [3] "Æðelberht I"                         "Æðelberht II and Eardwulf"          
## [5] "Æðelberht II, Ælfric and Eadberht I" "Æðelberht III"
```

Based upon the (not very clear) guidance in the [Encoding Issues](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Encoding-issues) section of Writing R Extensions I think I ought to be encoding the factor levels as UTF-8, but the obvious method doesn't work:

```
Encoding(levels(english_monarchs$name)) <- "utf8"  #each encoding still "unknown"
```

How can I make the data portable enough to be accepted on CRAN?

Comment: Not sure it makes any difference, but isn't it supposed to be `"UTF-8"`?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich R understands the encoding with or without the dash. `iconvlist()` contains both strings.

Comment: Odd, because some encodings are changed when I use `"UTF-8"` on 64-bit Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Comment: From `?Encoding`: Character strings in R can be declared to be in ‘"latin1"’ or ‘"UTF-8"’ or ‘"bytes"’.  You can't label strings with arbitrary encodings, as from `iconv`.

Comment: OK, `UTF-8` does correctly change encodings on my machine too.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a cool package -- what is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The thing that worked for me was to declare the encoding as `"latin1"`, and then use `iconv` to convert to UTF-8.

```
Encoding(levels(english_monarchs$name)) <- "latin1"
levels(english_monarchs$name) <- iconv(
  levels(english_monarchs$name), 
  "latin1", 
  "UTF-8"
)
```

Comment: seems like I'm hitting every one of your CRAN questions tonight! Have all the same issues!

Comment: ...or "latin2"  ;)