# detect non ascii characters in a string

Tags: r

How can I detect non-ascii characters in a vector of strings in a grep like fashion.  For example below I'd like to return `c(1, 3)` or `c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)`:

```
x <- c("façile test of showNonASCII(): details{", 
    "This is a good line", "This has an ümlaut in it.", "OK again. }")
```

Attempt:

```
y <- tools::showNonASCII(x)
str(y)
p <- capture.output(tools::showNonASCII(x))
```

Comment: Maybe `stringi::stri_enc_mark(x)`?

Comment: @David I think that will do it... can you throw down as an answer.  Maybe others will see an issue with it or have different solutions.

Comment: Why not fix the code so it handles Unicode properly instead?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will, that's easy, but this is to validate strings so I first need to detect if there's a problem with the data so as to inform the client.

Comment: Why are Latin1 characters considered a problem? Are you trying to detect some *other* problem perhaps, eg invalid codepage conversions?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos b/c it's data from a client.  We want it in a particular format.  Non-standard data format is a data scientist's enemy, particularly if you're trying to automate a task.  It's far easier and cheaper to get clients to put data in the correct format than to try to clean up and address un-foreseen errors later.

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934856/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-data-files)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

another possible way is to try to convert your string to ASCII and the try to detect all the generated *non printable control characters* which couldn't be converted

```
grepl("[[:cntrl:]]", stringi::stri_enc_toascii(x))
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Though it seems `stringi` has a built in function for this type of things too

```
stringi::stri_enc_mark(x)
# [1] "latin1" "ASCII"  "latin1" "ASCII"
```

Comment: Both solutions are terrific.  This one is a bit more compact and may be more robust to other encodings, though, admittedly, I know very little about encodings.

Answer (score 26):

Came across this later using pure base regex and so simple:

```
grepl("[^ -~]", x)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

More here: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/

Comment: From the link: "[ -~] matches all ASCII characters from the space to tilde. What are these characters? These are all printable characters!"

Comment: Short, simple, smart: simply beautiful!

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you extract the relevant code from `showNonASCII`?

```
x <- c("façile test of showNonASCII(): details{", 
       "This is a good line", "This has an ümlaut in it.", "OK again. }")

grepNonASCII <- function(x) {
  asc <- iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII")
  ind <- is.na(asc) | asc != x
  which(ind)
}

grepNonASCII(x)
#[1] 1 3
```

Comment: The iconv  function appears to remove the variable label attributes randomly in a dataframe when applied. What could be reasons?

Comment: @Heatshock I have no idea what you are doing. `iconv` should preserve attributes.

Comment: I read in a sas dataset in xpt format. here is code.  dv <-read_xpt('adsl.xpt').  dv1<-dv |>
   mutate(across(everything(), ~iconv(.,"latin2", "ascii") ))     then use str(dv1). Some of the variable labels get lost in a consistent way. but not all variables. Do you know why?

Comment: No, I don't. Might be due to your use of dplyr.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late I guess but it could be useful for the next readers.

You can find these functions:

- `showNonASCII(<character_vector>)`
- `showNonASCIIfile(<file>)`

in the `tools` R package (see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/showNonASCII.html). It does exactly what is asked here: show non ASCII characters in a string or in a text file.

Answer (score 3):

A `stringr` regex solution:

```r
library(stringr)
x <- c("façile test of showNonASCII(): details{", 
    "This is a good line",
    "This has an ümlaut in it.", "OK again. }")
str_detect(x, "[^[:ascii:]]")
# => [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The `[^[:ascii:]]` pattern matches any non-ASCII character.

The `[[:ascii:]]` pattern matches any ASCII character.

If you ever need to make sure the *whole* string consists of non-ASCII chars, use

```r
str_detect(x, "^[^[:ascii:]]+\\z")
```

where `^` matches the start of string and `\z` matches the very end of string.