# Finding Farsi or non English text in a file

Tags: r

I have a raw data (csv file) which I loaded to R studio and I want to extract those columns which have non english data in it how could possibly I can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613761/detect-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect non ascii characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613761/detect-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string). If not, can you please add a sample data and clarify your question?

Comment: @DJV yes like I have a csv file with columns name, last name, city, address
in these columns suppose city might have names like: New York, Delhi, کابل, تهران

so I want to find those values which are not in English with their column name

Comment: Came across this by chance: `grepl("[^ -~]", x)`. This matches any non-ASCII character; for more info check out  http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/

Comment: For example: `x <- c("New York", "Delhi", "کابلت  هران", "ü", "ß")
grepl("[^ -~]", x)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stringi` package.

I will use @Chris Ruehlemann sample data.

Sample data:

```
x <- c("New York", "Delhi", "کابلت هران", "ü", "ß") 

library(stringi)

grepl("[[:cntrl:]]", stringi::stri_enc_toascii(x))
```

Which will give you a `TRUE`/`FALSE` output:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Next, you can extract the non English values:

```
x[grepl("[[:cntrl:]]", stringi::stri_enc_toascii(x))]
[1] "کابلت هران" "ü"          "ß"
```

If you'd like you can also use the base R solution:

```
grepl("[^ -~]", x)
```

Which will give you similar results:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However, if you'll benchmark both function, `stringi::stri_enc_toascii` is faster.

```
library(rbenchmark)

# sample data
y <- sample(x, 1000, replace = TRUE)

benchmark(
  "stringi" = {
    grepl("[[:cntrl:]]", stringi::stri_enc_toascii(y))
    },
"baseR" = {
  grepl("[^ -~]", y)
},
replications = 1000,
columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
            "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))

     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2   baseR         1000    0.96    5.053      0.96     0.00
1 stringi         1000    0.19    1.000      0.19     0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you want to select *columns* in your data frame whose names have the non-ASCII characters, here's a simple R base solution for that.
Let's assume your data has this structure:

```
df <- data.frame(
  NY = c("some", "data", "more", "data"),
  Delhi = c("some", "data", "more", "data"),
  کابل = c("some", "data", "more", "data"),
  ß = c("some", "data", "more", "data")
)
df
    NY Delhi کابل    ß
1 some  some some some
2 data  data data data
3 more  more more more
4 data  data data data
```

Then all you have to do is subset `df`on the columns of interest using `grepl` to find matches of the pattern `[^ -~]` in `colnames`:

```
df[ , grepl("[^ -~]", colnames(df))]
  کابل    ß
1 some some
2 data data
3 more more
4 data data
```

Comment: Thank you but I said data in a column I work that as below but it takes a little time to execute

Comment: raw_data <- read_excel("./input/Extracted AFG1904_Emergency SNFI & Winterisation Assessment - all versions - False - 2019-12-23-04-50-46.xlsx")

#Creates an empty data frame 
new_df <- data.frame(UUID = character(0), question_id = character(0), original_value = character(0))

Comment: #Creates variables for to_be_translated data frame
uuid <- vector()
question <- vector()
original_value <- vector()

#Looking for un-translated values

Comment: for(coli in 1:ncol(raw_data)){
      
    for(rowi in 1:nrow(raw_data)){
      result <- grepl(raw_data[rowi,coli], "[^\u0001-\u007F]+" )
      
      if(result == TRUE){
        uuid <- c(uuid, as.character(raw_data[rowi, "_uuid"]))
        question <- (c(question, names(raw_data[coli])))
        original_value <- c(original_value, as.character(raw_data[rowi, coli]))
      }
      
    }
    # Feedback
    cat("\014")
    print (paste("Logging Column", coli, "of", length(raw_data)))
  }

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what you are trying to communicate to me. Did the two answers you have received so far *not* answer your question? If so, can you specify in clear terms what is missing?