# Converting accents to ASCII in R

Tags: r, unicode, diacritics, transliteration, stringi

I'm trying to convert special characters to ASCII in R. I tried using Hadley's advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934856/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-data-files):

```
stringi::stri_trans_general('Jos\xe9', 'latin-ascii')
```

But I get "Jos�". I'm using stringi v1.1.1.

I'm running a Mac. My friends who are running Windows machines seem to get the desired result of "Jose".

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Store the result in a variable. Let's call it `s`. What is the result of `sapply(1:nchar(s), function(i){ return(charToRaw(substr(s, i, i))) })` on Mac? On Windows, the result is a `raw` vector with values `4a 6f 73 65`.

Comment: Also, is `"latin-ascii"` included in `stringi::stri_trans_list()`? Does `stringi::stri_trans_general('Jos\xe9', 'Latin-ASCII')` work as you expect?

Comment: When running the sapply snippet you mentioned, I get: "Error in nchar(s) : invalid multibyte string, element 1". Using 'Latin-ASCII' instead of 'latin-ascii' doesn't help either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default encoding on Windows is different from the typical default encoding on other operating systems (UTF-8). `x ='Jos\xe9'` means something in 
Latin1, but not in UTF-8. So, on Linux or OS X you need to tell R what the encoding is:

```
x ='Jos\xe9'
Encoding(x) <- 'latin1'
stri_trans_general(x, 'Latin-ASCII')
```

Comment: ...and if the above string wasn't latin1-encoded, e.g., `stri_conv()` would be useful.