# Transliterating a vector of strings with mixed encodings to latin1

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I have vector with names of countries such as x

```
x <- c("c\u00f4te", "côte")

showNonASCII(x)
1: c<c3><b4>te
2: c<f4>te


iconv(x, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "cA?te" "cote" 

Encoding(x)
[1] "UTF-8"  "latin1"
```

I would like to unify them, so how can I use str_replace to convert 
\u00f4 to  ô.
and convert x elements to latin1?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the encoding of the vector elements:

```
x <- c("c\u00f4te", "côte", , "cote")
sapply(x, Encoding, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

I get a mix. So, iconv can't be called on the whole vector due to having a fixed "from" encoding.

stringi does provide a nice wrapper function that both adapts to different "from" encodings and transliterates to ASCII.

```
stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "latin-ascii")
```

Comment: Good answer. what if I want all vector's elements to become latin1 or UTF-8. ie replace to "c\u00f4te",  "cote" to become  "côte" or 
"côte" , "cote" to become "c\u00f4te"

Comment: @Mohamed How would any kind of conversion know that "cote" is more properly written in French as  "côte"?

Comment: I work on data of 57 countries one of Côte d'Ivoire and Réunion.
I do my calculation on R, then I export the dataframe (one column is country and other columns are indicator, and years) using write.csv. However when I open the file in excel, c\u00f4 become A with telda. So I want to export in latin1 with côte not cote.

Comment: I came through an article that \x is used for letters in latin1.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930717/converting-accents-to-ascii-in-r
so \x00f4 is  ô  in latin1....