# R: Convert wrong display of foreign characters into a correct encoding (double mojibake)

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, stringr, stringi

In R, I have vectors like this:

```
TEST <- c("BlAA¶schl, G", "ThAA¶ni, A.")
```

whereby `BlAA¶schl` schould be `Blöschl`, and `ThAA¶ni` should be `Thöni`.

There are similar problems throughout a whole dataset. I don't know how it is termed (maybe "non-ASCII characters"?).

Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931724/14308375), others seem to have tried this code successfully:

```
Encoding(TEST) <- 'latin1'
stringi::stri_trans_general(TEST, 'Latin-ASCII')
```

But in my case, nothing changes.

What can I do to convert characters like `AA¶` to `ö`?

---

**EDIT**: The key problem, it seems, is that there is a "double [mojibake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931724/14308375)" as *JosefZ* mentioned in the comments.

**EDIT 2**: I found this "[UTF-8 Character Debug Tool](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)" which contains some (not all) of the problems in the `actual` and `expected` columns. In addition, [this "encoding repairer" on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/xijo/d4bad3953f7b9979dd91) seems to offer what I need, but it is not written in R.

Comment: this works fine on Linux with UTF-8... what is your encoding? check Sys.getenv() output?

Comment: @user12256545, interesting, thank you. I use Windows. Where I can find my "encoding" in `Sys.getenv()`?

Comment: You can't as it looks like a _double_ [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (moreover, somewhat mangled), cf. the following _Python_   example: `'ö'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1').encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')` returns `'Ã\x83Â¶'`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @JosefZ! But if it is impossible, how comes that the other user (in the comments here) was able to do it in Linux?

Comment: This works for me starting from `TEST <- c("Bl\xf6schl, G", "Thöni, A.")`. I'm on Windows where `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")` returns `[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"`.and `stringi::stri_escape_unicode( TEST)` returns `[1] "Bl\\u00f6schl, G" "Th\\u00f6ni, A."`

Comment: I have the same result, @JosefZ, but it does not work with `BlAA¶schl` as a starting point. So I suppose it really does indicate a "double mojibake" that cannot be rescued? By the way, my `Sys.getlocale(category="LC_ALL")` returns: `LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better, more efficient & automated solutions.

But I tried it manually: I looked at all "mojibakes" and changed them with `gsub` manually:

```
TEST <- c("BlAA¶schl, G", "ThAA¶ni, A.")

TEST <- gsub("Ã¶", "ö", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ã¼", "ü", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Å¾", "z", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ã¡", "á", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ã¤", "ä", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ä‡", "ć", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ã", "Á", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("ÃŸ", "ß", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ã£", "ã", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ã©", "é", TEST)
TEST <- gsub("Ä", "č", TEST)
```

It works, but there's always the risk of omitting some characters if the dataset is too large.