# what is the best way to remove non-ASCII characters from a text Corpus when using Quanteda in R?

Tags: r, nlp, tm, corpus, quanteda

I am in dire need. I have a corpus that I have converted into a common language, but some of the words were not properly converted into English. Therefore, my corpus has non-ASCII characters such as `U+00F8`.

I am using Quanteda and I have imported my text using this code:

```
 EUCorpus <- corpus(textfile(file="/Users/RiohBurke/Documents/RStudio/PROJECT/*.txt"), encodingFrom = "UTF-8-BOM")
```

My corpus consists of 166 documents. Having imported the documents into R, what would be the best way to get rid of these non-ASCII characters?

Comment: You can do this with iconv . See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9935242/5151349

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
texts(EUCorpus) <- iconv(texts(EUCorpus), from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII", sub = "")
```

This converts the encoding to ASCII, replacing any non-translatable characters (those not in the 0-127 ASCII range) to nothingness.

Comment: is `gsub('[^ -~]', '', x)` a possible approach that might be faster?  I'm on vacation so no R to test myself.

Comment: How do we know to convert from UTF-8 to ASCII?  A document detailing this would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `file mytextfile.txt` at the Terminal, this lists known encodings for text files. There are also some detection methods in **stringi**, i.e. `stri_enc_detect()`.

Comment: I prefer to use regex as suggested by @TylerRinker to enable additional manipulations (like removing extra spaces) and I use hex values for readability i.e. `"[^\x20-\x7E]` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50398057/5420406)