# How to remove strange characters using gsub in R?

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to clean up some text that was loaded into memory using `readLines(..., encoding='UTF-8')`.

If I don't specify the encoding, I see all kinds of strange characters like:

```
> "The way I talk to my family......i would get my ass beat to
> DEATH....but they kno I cray cray & just leave it at that
> ðŸ˜œðŸ˜â˜º'"
```

This is what it looks like after readLines(..., encoding='UTF-8'):

```
> "The way I talk to my family......i would get my ass beat to
> DEATH....but they  kno I cray cray & just leave it at that
> \xf0\u009f\u0098\u009c\xf0\u009f\u0098\u009d☺"
```

You can see the unicode literals at the end: \u009f, \u0098, etc.

I can't find the right command and regular expression to get rid of these. I've tried:

```
gsub('[^[:punct:][:alnum:][\\s]]', '', text)
```

I also tried specifying the unicode characters, but I believe they're getting interpreted as text:

```
gsub('\u009', '', text) # Unchanged
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use regular expressions, you can keep only those characters you want using a range of ASCII codes:

```
text = "The way I talk to my family......i would get my ass beat to 
DEATH....but they kno I cray cray & just leave it at that ðŸ˜œðŸ˜â˜º'"

gsub('[^\x20-\x7E]', '', text)

# [1] "The way I talk to my family......i would get my ass beat to DEATH....but they kno I cray cray & just leave it at that '"
```

Below is a table of ASCII codes taken from asciitable.com:

[image]

You can see that I am removing any character not within the range of x20 (SPACE) and x7E (~).

Comment: This is much better than iconv!

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to get rid of these characters is to convert from utf-8 to ascii:

```
combined_doc <- iconv(combined_doc, 'utf-8', 'ascii', sub='')
```