# Replace square bracket with bracket using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I want to change "[" too "(" in a a data.frame (class is string) but i get the following error:

> Error in gsub("[", "(", df) : 
>       invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''

Doing the revers works perfectly:

```
df <- gsub("]",")", df)
```

all "]" got replaced in the data.frame df

so in essence this is the problem

```
df <- gsub("[","(", df)
```

> Error in gsub("[", "(", df) : 
>             invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''

can anyone help to fix the code 
or is there an alternative function to gsub which can accomplish the same?

Comment: Square brackets and parentheses are regex _metacharacters_ which have a special meaning when inside a regex pattern.  So, you should escape them.  I don't know why the second version is working though, this is interesting.

Comment: When using gsub (or any other function that uses a pattern, like grep), you have to take into account whether that pattern includes metacharacters, and if so, escaping their 'normal' function by adding '\\' in front of it.

Comment: This is more appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828620/how-to-remove-strange-characters-using-gsub-in-r/50398057#50398057

Answer (score 3):

The `[` is. a metacharacter, so we may need either `fixed = TRUE` or escaping `\\[`

```
gsub("[", "(", df, fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the Hexadecimal representation of the ASCII character `[` by prefixing it with `\\x`:

```
gsub('\\x5B', '(', '[')
# [1] "("
```

Just a preference, but I find this to be more readable in cases where the metacharacter `[` and `]` is mixed with it's literal/escaped version. For example I find this:

```
gsub('[\\x5B\\x5D]+', '(', ']][[[', perl = TRUE)
```

more readable than these:

```
gsub('[\\]\\[]+', '(', ']][[[', perl = TRUE)
[1] "("

gsub('[][]+', '(', ']][[[', perl = TRUE)
[1] "("

gsub('[\\[\\]]+', '(', ']][[[', perl = TRUE)
[1] "("
```

especially when you have a long and complicated pattern.

Here is the ASCII table I used from http://www.asciitable.com/

[image]

The obvious disadvantage is that you have to lookup the hex code from the table.