# as.numeric returns NA for no apparent reason for some of the values in a column

Tags: r, na

While trying to convert a column of characters (strings of numbers, e.g "0.1234") into numeric, using as.numeric, some of the values are returned `NA` with the warning 'NAs introduced by coercion'. The characters that are returned as `NA`s don't seem to be any different from the ones that are returned as numeric correctly. Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Already tried to look for any characters that are not numeric (as ',') that can hide inside some of the values. I did find strings containing '-' (e.g "-0.123") that really turned into `NA`s, but these are only part of the strings turned into `NA`s. Also, tried to look for spaces inside the strings. that doesn't seem to be the problem as well.

```
data$y
 [1] "0.833250539"  "0.820323535"  "0.462284612"  "0.792943985"  "0.860587952"  "0.729665177"  "0.461503956"  "0.625871118" 
 [9] "0.740999346"  "0.962727964"  "0.971089266"  "0.869004848"  "0.828651766"  "0.900648732"  "0.970326033"  "0.898123286" 
[17] "0.911640765"  "0.902442126"  "0.843392097"  "0.763421844"  "0.892426243"  "0.380433624"  "0.925017633"  "0.725470821" 
[25] "0.699924767"  "0.689061225"  "0.907462936"  "0.888064239"  "0.913547115"  "-‬0.625103904‭" "0.897385961"  "0.889727462" 
[33] "0.90127339"   "0.947012474"  "0.948883588"  "0.845845512"  "0.97866966"   "0.796247738"  "0.864627056"  "0.266656189‭" 
[41] "0.894915463"  "0.969690678"  "0.771365656‭"  "0.88304436"   "0.954039006"  "0.836952199"  "0.731558669‭"  "0.907224294" 
[49] "0.622059127"  "0.887742343"  "0.917550343"  "0.97240334‭"   "0.902841957"  "0.617403052"  "0.82926708"   "0.674903846" 
[57] "0.947132958"  "0.929213613‭"  "-‬0.297844476" "0.871767367"

y = as.numeric(data$y)
```

> Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion

```
y
 [1] 0.8332505 0.8203235 0.4622846 0.7929440 0.8605880 0.7296652 0.4615040 0.6258711 0.7409993 0.9627280 0.9710893 0.8690048 0.8286518
[14] 0.9006487 0.9703260 0.8981233 0.9116408 0.9024421 0.8433921 0.7634218 0.8924262 0.3804336 0.9250176 0.7254708 0.6999248 0.6890612
[27] 0.9074629 0.8880642 0.9135471        NA 0.8973860 0.8897275 0.9012734 0.9470125 0.9488836 0.8458455 0.9786697 0.7962477 0.8646271
[40]        NA 0.8949155 0.9696907        NA 0.8830444 0.9540390 0.8369522        NA 0.9072243 0.6220591 0.8877423 0.9175503        NA
[53] 0.9028420 0.6174031 0.8292671 0.6749038 0.9471330        NA        NA 0.8717674
```

Comment: Although very nice with pasting in your data and code, I agree something is amiss. Could you please paste your data using the `dput` command? If your data frame is too large, then just a subset that includes some of the values that are returned as `NA`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828620/how-to-remove-strange-characters-using-gsub-in-r

Answer (score 2):

Your strings contain some non-unicode characters. If you are certain that it is safe to remove them, use

```
as.numeric(iconv(data$y, 'utf-8', 'ascii', sub=''))
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828621/6138593) on the conversion

Comment: That worked great for me. All of the numbers seem to be exactly the same as they looked as strings, so I don't really understand what characters were the problem, but it worked nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Copy and pasting your character gives me (for the example of the last `NA`) `"-,0.297844476"`. There is something wrong with the encoding. You can work around by using

```
as.numeric(gsub(",","",data$y))
```

**edit**  This answer does not work on all your `NA`s... I don't really know what is going on with your data, please provide a `dput` if possible.