# How to remove invalid characters in a JSON file in R?

Tags: r, encoding

I would like to fetch data from a Reddit page but I'm having a problem converting into JSON with the RJSONIO package. It works for others Reddit pages but this one is causing me headache because it return `invalid JSON input`.

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)

json <- getURL("https://www.reddit.com/r/burstcoin/new.json?sort=rising?limit=100")

list <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)
Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input

> Encoding(json)
[1] "UTF-8"
```

I've try to remove non-ASCII characters with `iconv` but it doesn't give the expected result and I still have the same error.

```
json <- iconv(json, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub="")

> Encoding(json)
[1] "unknown"
```

I also use the stringi package which provides a function for general unicode conversion but still the same error.

```
library(stringi)
json <- stringi::stri_trans_general(json, "latin-ascii")
```

How can I parse this JSON file ?

Similar question : [Removing non-ASCII characters from data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934856/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-data-files)

Comment: list <- fromJSON(toJSON(json))

Comment: Using jsonlite instead of RJSONIO. Returns a character vector.

Comment: I have an error with `jsonlite` as well : `lexical error: invalid character inside string.`

Comment: Did you wrap your fromJSON around toJSON? I used your link and the lexical error disappears when I use list <- fromJSON(toJSON(json)

Comment: Correct but I need to run `json <- fromJSON(toJSON(json))` to remove invalid character and then `list <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)` to get a list. Great, thanks ! Could you explain how it works ?

Comment: Data structures in R do not perfectly map to their JSON counterparts, and leave some ambiguity for edge cases. The jsonlite library was developed to offer a more concrete mapping, not available in other R json libraries. My assumption is jsonlite's more refined implementation of parsing/encoding preps your json so that your final mapping to a list structure is made possible. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2805.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been given by user @Cybernetic in the comment section and works perfectly :

```
json <- getURL("https://www.reddit.com/r/burstcoin/new.json?sort=rising?limit=100")
json <- fromJSON(toJSON(json))
list <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)
```