# How to remove Registered, Trademark, and Copyright symbols from a string?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with object names. Some of the objects have special symbols like ® and ™

Example:
ProStand® Front Air Suspension 
OnCo™ Connector

I've tried 
`db[grep("®",db$objectName), ]` to find the special symbols but R isn't picking it up even though I see them in the dataframe.

This didn't work either
`db$objectName[db$objectName == "ProStand® Front Air Suspension" ]<- "ProStand Front Air Suspension"`

How do I find the special characters and remove them from the strings in my dataframe?

Comment: `gsub("[®™]", "", db$objectName)`

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934856/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-data-files ; `x = c("ProStand® Front Air Suspension", "OnCo™ Connector") ; iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one by matching the unicode character and replace it with blank

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(str1, "\\u00AE|\\u00a9|\\u2122", "")
#[1] "ProStand Front Air Suspension"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "ProStand® Front Air© Suspension™"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something a little bit more generic, using `stringr`, you could try with, for example:

`str_remove(string = "ProStand® Front Air Suspension", pattern = "[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+")`

which gives

`"ProStand Front Air Suspension"`

This basically removes everything that is not a number, not a letter, and not a space.