# How do I remove certain special character in my column

Tags: r, special-characters

Currently I have a column containing these special characters:

N700��

N713��

And I was wondering if there was a way to remove them?

test_df is the name of the dataframe and I'm trying to remove the special characters from these rows using the following:

```
test_df$TailNum <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", "", test_df$TailNum)
```

> Error in gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", "", test_df$TailNum) :
> input string 1 is invalid
> In addition: Warning message:
> In gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", "", test_df$TailNum) :
> unable to translate 'N700' to a wide string

```
test_df[!grepl("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", test_df$TailNum), ]
```

> Error in df[!grepl("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", test_df$TailNum), ] :
> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: I tested `x = "N700��"` .   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935242/13203906 lead me to `iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")` .

Comment: Have you tried `gsub("\uFFFD", "", c("N700��", "N713��"), fixed = TRUE)`?

Comment: Hi there thank you @VinceGreg for the answer! That helped to remove the special characters from the entire column!!

Answer (score 1):

Since my comment got a good feedback from the original poster, here is an answer. [This answer remove non-ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935242/13203906) with  `iconv()`. With a `dplyr::mutate()`:

```
data.frame(
  value = c("N289", "N182", "N700��", "N713��", "N895")
) %>% mutate( value2 = iconv(value, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  value = c("N289", "N182", "N700��", "N713��", "N895")
)

test_df <- test_df %>%
  mutate(value = gsub("�+", "", value))
```

For output:

```
 id  value
1  1 N289
2  2 N182
3  3 N700
4  4 N713
5  5 N895
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply! But when i try to do it input this into my dataframe, i get this error
test_df <- test_df %>%
  mutate(TailNum = gsub("�+", "", TailNum))

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `TailNum = gsub("�+", "", TailNum)`.
Caused by error in `gsub()`:
! input string 1 is invalid
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: If you edit your question to include a small reproducible dataset that we can run to get the error, can provide a more tailored answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the special chars you want to remove are non-ASCII chars, here's a nice pattern `[^ -~]` to get rid of them:

```
library(stringr)
test_df %>%
  mutate(value = str_remove_all(value, "[^ -~]"))
```